# Parse XML in JQUERY - Nodes are listing as one item rather than separate list items

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, each

I'm trying to obtain each trail name and status from this XML file into individual list items. The result I'm getting is all trails combined into one list item and for the status only the first one.

RESULT:

- Trail 1Trail 2Trail 3Trail 4Trail 5Trail 6List item
- Open

XML:

```
<ZONE ZONENAME="Lower Mountain">
<TRAILNAME STATUS="Open">Trail 1</TRAILNAME>
<TRAILNAME STATUS="Open">Trail 2</TRAILNAME>
<TRAILNAME STATUS="Closed">Trail 3</TRAILNAME>
<TRAILNAME STATUS="Open">Trail 4</TRAILNAME>
<TRAILNAME STATUS="Open">Trail 5</TRAILNAME>
<TRAILNAME STATUS="Open">Trail 6</TRAILNAME>
</ZONE>
```

JQuery:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "bike.xml",
 dataType: "xml",
 success: function(data) {
    $(data).find('ZONE[ZONENAME="Lower Mountain"]').each(function(index){
          trails = $(data).find('TRAILNAME').text();
          status = $(data).find('TRAILNAME').attr('STATUS');
        $('.LeftBox').append('<li>'+trails+'</li>');
        $('.RightBox').append('<li>'+status+'</li>');
    });
   }
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
var myxml = $.parseXML(xml);
    $(myxml).find('ZONE[ZONENAME="Lower Mountain"]').find('TRAILNAME').each(function (index, item) {
        alert($(this).text());
        alert($(this).attr('STATUS'));
    });
```

Check sample on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VxtGm/

Comment: Fantastic! This completely works.  Thank you so much and appreciate the fiddle code.  Cheers.